# Sci-fi movie with a giant spaceship (or something) used like Noah’s Ark

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

I watched this movie some years ago and only remember a scene in particular, near the final, when many animals (or creatures?) are on a conveyor belt and are going into a great spaceship. The scene takes place I remember in an enoumous ambient where is placed the spaceship, and this ambient is mainly pink-red in color (not very sure about this).
Sorry but don’t remember any more details.
I’m sure it is a Hollywood movie, not very old (no more than 10-20 years), and almost sure not an animation movie.
Anyone may help me to identify it?

Comment: [When Worlds Collide](https://youtu.be/YN_siKJXevU?t=58m26s)?

Comment: [Sky Captain and the World of Tomorrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sky_Captain_and_the_World_of_Tomorrow) had a scene towards the end where animals were being put into a spaceship intended as an ark.

Comment: Yes, I think you got it! Watched it now and in fact it's a very short scene; and in a following scene we see the ship that's in pink-red color. Thanks, Andrew!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Echoing [Andrew Thompson's comment](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/566/andrew-thompson), I'm fairly sure this is [Sky Captain and the World of Tomorrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sky_Captain_and_the_World_of_Tomorrow). The scene you've described is below and the background "ambient" often includes backgrounds in pink and red.

I can easily see how the sort of noir-style colouration could make you think it was an animated feature.

[image]

Comment: I wasn't sure about the conveyor, but that seals it.  Great animation!  :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson - Cheers. SE, like film should also be a visual medium :-)